# Unable to use huggingface-cli in Jupyterhub

Tags: huggingface-transformers, jupyterhub, huggingface

I created my model using HuggingFace Transformers. When I try to push to HuggingFace Hub, it shows the following error when I execute `trainer.push_to_hub()`:

```
OSError: Failed to start custom transfer command "huggingface-cli" remote: exec: 
"huggingface-cli": executable file not found in $PATH
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://my_hugging_face_url_with_login_token'
```

The command can be used in the Terminal opened in Jupyterhub without a problem. How to resolve this PATH issue in Jupyterhub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`huggingface-hub` in fact has a Python implementation:

To login to the HuggingFace, we can use the following codes (if you don't mind to display the token in plain text in your code):

```
import huggingface_hub
huggingface_hub.login('hf_TOKEN_HERE')
```

Executing `!huggingface-cli login` in Notebook is not always working, as the token input box might not appear in some Notebook versions and requires user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Run !huggingface-cli login and enter your huggingface token, which you can generate from the huggingface website

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).